# Why do I get this group-by error in a for-loop in pl/sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm writing an sql procedure and I have to use a for-loop, something like this:

```
for a in (select first, second
           from table1 t1 join
                table2 t2
                on t1.x = t2.x
           group by t1.id,first,second
          ) loop
```

and I got this error **Error(12,64): PL/SQL: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here**

If you have any idea what could be, please share. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `group by` columns and your `select` columns are not compatible.  The error seems pretty obvious.  However, what you want to do is quite unclear, so it is hard to make any suggestions.  If I had to speculate, you want `order by`, not `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry it was my mistake there. Even without my mistake still get that error

Comment: . . When you fix the query, I would imagine it is the extra parentheses starting at `(`.

Comment: I am sorry, but your credibility is shot. You already had to edit the code twice, to modify what you posted initially. I suspect what you have right now is still not the exact code that throws that error. What's wrong with **Copy and Paste**? Look for a group function you may have used in a `WHERE` clause or perhaps even in `GROUP BY` in that block. (Even assuming that the error does come from that block...)

Comment: @mathguy if u think is gonna help, my copy pasta code is here: 

`for c in (select s.id,avg(nvl(valoare,0)) from studenti s join note n on s.id=n.id_student join cursuri c on n.id_curs=c.id group by s.id,c.an,c.semestru order by s.id,c.semestru) loop`

Comment: I just created minimal tables with the names and the columns from your code, and put that in a small anonymous block. It compiled and executed without error. Are you sure the error comes from this part of your code?

Comment: A few observations: `valoare` probably comes from `note`, you should qualify it with the table alias. You must give an alias to the `avg` computation in `select` if you are going to use it somewhere. Also - not sure if `valoare` of `null` must be considered 0 - is that the business meaning? If not, then the `nvl` should be outside the `avg` call, not within it. But, anyway, none of these have anything to do with the error you reported. Are you perhaps using `avg(...)` as is, somewhere **else** in your code? (Since you didn't give it an alias in the query?)

Comment: @mathguy now if i'm thinking that nvl is useless. Also i need to add that avg to that value in a nested table, but my compiler doesn't recognise my alias and it's pretty strange. That avg calculate average semester grade in each year for a student and I haven't found any other solution than this for

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY can only be used with an aggregate function - I would suggest trying this:

create or replace procedure first_second is

```
begin
   for c in (select t1.id as ID, 
         t2.variable as variable, 
         avg(x) as average  
         from table1 t1
 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
 group by t1.id, t1.variable)

 loop
   dbms_output.put_line ('The average' || c.ID || ' is ' || c.average);
   exit when c.average <=0;
 end loop;
end first_second;
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does exactly and why it works better than the code from the question? A link to the documentation for more context would be nice.

Comment: @tobib, I wrote this based on the question, so I unfortunately don't have any documentation. I created a cursor that would read each line of the joined tables and printing the results using dbms.print. The cursor exits when the aggregate variable being calculated (e.g. average) is zero, or when there are no more lines left in the temporary table. The "group function not allowed here" error is a result of grouping by the aggregate variable. When grouping, all columns not being aggregated must be listed in the GROUP BY clause. Similarly, it's impossible to group by an aggregate function.